# How to let the parent component trigger the event of the child component without using refs in VueJs

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

```
  <template v-for='item in 777'>
    <ParentComponent>
      <ChildComponent /
    </ParentComponent>
  </template>
```

Now, I want some events in ParentComponent to trigger some events in ChildComponent, however it's rendering generated components, I don't want to use Ref and prove&inject to do this, is there a more elegant way to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with scoped slot, prop and watcher:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({})
app.component('parent', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <button @click="trigger = true">evt</button>
      <slot :trig="trigger"></slot>
    </div>
  `,
  data: () => ({
    trigger: false,
  }),
})
app.component('child', {
  template: `
    <div>{{ evt }}</div>
  `,
  props: {
    trig: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
    evt: 'a',
  }),
  watch: {
    trig(val) {
      if(val) this.trigEvt()
    }
  },
  methods: {
    trigEvt() {
       this.evt = 'b'
    }
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <template v-for='item in 7'>
    <parent>
      <template v-slot="{trig}">
        <child :trig="trig"></child>
      </template>
    </parent>
  </template>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I have considered this solution before, but I feel that this will make the system complicated, I would like to know what api can be used by vue to get the instance of the nested child component directly inside the parent component when compiling such parent-child nested components